# circular motion relative velocity question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, relative-motion

You are standing in the middle of a disk of radius $2\:\mathrm{m}$ rotating at $\pi\:\mathrm{rad s^{-1}}$, and there's a smooth puck at $1.5\:\mathrm{m}$ away from the centre. If the puck was released, what is the relative velocity of the pluck from you? i.e. how would you observe it?

I saw an answer trying to vectorally take away the velocity of the edge of the disk from the velocity of the puck, but I think it's wrong because if you just replace the disk with a larger one, the answer using this approach would be changed, but I think it shouldn't.

I'm sure there is an animation showing this, but I can't find any. Would be much appreciated if anyone could find one.

Comment: I believe you've meant 'puck,' but 'pluck' evokes the image of a defeathered fowl scrabbling about on a slick merry-go-round, which is substantially more engaging as an experimental setup.

Comment: Concerning the question, are you taking friction into account? A frictionless treatment allows a simple mathematical solution, while frictional treatment requires more initial conditions and data and allows, eventually, a synchronous 'orbit' for the puck.

Comment: Ah my bad, it's a smooth puck so no friction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the diagram below:

It shows you and the puck on the rotating disc. Since as you're in the centre of the disk the puck is rotating around you. The disc is rotating with an angular velocity $\omega=\pi\:\mathrm{rads^{-s}}$.

[image: You and the puck]

Pictured is the tangential velocity vector $\vec{v}$ which of course changes every instant as the position vector $\vec{r}$ changes every instant. This change in direction is caused by the centripetal acceleration, in vector notation $\vec{a_c}$:

$$\vec{a_c}=\frac{d \vec{v}}{dt}$$

This acceleration acc. Newton requires a centripetal force $\vec{F_c}$, as:

$$\vec{F_c}=m\vec{a_c},$$

where $m$ is the mass of the puck and $\vec{F_c}$ is on the same line and points in the same direction as $\vec{a_c}$.

Now imagine that at the instant the diagram represents, we release the puck, that is we remove $\vec{F_c}$ altogether, then acc. Newton's Law the puck *will simply continue to move along the line and direction of $\vec{v}$*. And without friction or any other forces acting on it... forever so! The linear speed (scalar) will be $v=1.5 \times \pi \:\mathrm{m/s}$ or $4.71\:\mathrm{m/s}$.

Regards the question of relative velocity it doesn't make a great deal of sense because the observer is not translating. One can say that the relative velocity of the puck with regards to the observer, in the *horizontal direction* it is zero, while in the *vertical direction* it is $v=1.5 \times \pi \:\mathrm{m/s}$.

**Edit:**

OP seems also interested in how long it would take for the puck to leave the disc altogether (without friction). That time is essentially the time to cover the distance between the puck at time of release (call it point $P$, call $O$ the centre of the disc) and the point $E$, that is $|PE|$. With Pythagoras we know:

$$R^2=|OP|^2+|PE|^2$$

$$|PE|=\sqrt{R^2-|OP|^2}$$

$$|PE|=\sqrt{2^2-1.5^2}=1.32\:\mathrm{m}$$

The time $t$ to cover that distance is:

$$t=\frac{|PE|}{v}=\frac{1.32}{4.71}=0.28\:\mathrm{s}$$

Comment: A nice answer as always, but did you not skip this question:

"What is the relative velocity of the pluck from you?"

Comment: @AshishGupta: as the observer is stationary, the concept of relative speed is really a bit surplus to requirement here, don't you think? :)

Comment: Yeah I know. Not really required here but it has been asked by the questioner. Anyway, if you don't mind, can you tell me this: If in this case, the initial velocity of the puck had an x component, how would that be affected over time?

Comment: @AshishGupta: same principle: any $\vec{v_x}$ would be conserved at the instant of release. Remember that $x$ and $y$-components are *independent* of each other.

Comment: Does that mean that we will have to deal with $v_x$ and $v_y$ separately and that they will both be affected by the circular motion over time? (Because after some time, there will be a component of the acceleration which will affect $v_x$ if I'm not wrong.)

Comment: @AshishGupta: construct a composite vector: $\vec{v}=\vec{v_x}+\vec{v_y}$ (vector addition!) At the instant of release that vector is conserved.

Comment: @Gert thanks for this answer, but yes, I would like the answer to the relative velocity please. The observer is stationary but it is rotating so from the observer the puck won't be moving in a straight line. If I'm not making sense, please look at: http://www.physics.ox.ac.uk/olympiad/Downloads/PastPapers/BPhO_Round_1_2013_prt_1.pdf question m, where I took the question from.

Comment: @VincentL: I've edited the answer accordingly. The answer reflects to fact that non-physicists *intuitively* expect the puck to start moving *centrifugally* (radially outwards) but that is not the case. It keeps on it tangential trajectory. And that is what an unbiased observer sees.

Comment: @Gert hmm... could you take a look at http://www.physics.ox.ac.uk/olympiad/Downloads/PastPapers/BPhO_Round%20_1_2013_MS.pdf Q1 m ii, which is basically the question I asked, but it gives a different answer.

Comment: @VincentL: Of course. In the question in the paper you linked to it says "A smooth flat horizontal turntable 4.0 m in diameter is rotating at 0.050 revs per second. But in the question you asked it is: "You are standing in the middle of a disk of radius 2m rotating at πrads−1". Different numbers in the question, different numbers in the answer!

Comment: @VincentL: in your question, $R_{puck}=1.5\:\mathrm{m}$, $\omega=\pi\:\mathrm{rads^{-1}}$, so $v_{puck}=\omega R_{puck}=1.5 \times \pi\:\mathrm{m/s}$.

Comment: @VincentL: in the Physics Olympiad: $R_{puck}=1.5\:\mathrm{m}$ and $f_{puck}=0.05\:\mathrm{s^{-s}}$, so $v_{puck}=2\pi f_{puck}R_{puck}=0.15 \times \pi\:\mathrm{m/s}$.

Comment: @Gert okay, the speed makes sense, but how about the angle? I still don't see how the mark scheme got the angle it says.

Comment: @VincentL: The first question (of **m** in the 'Olympiads' paper) is "(i) How long does the puck remain on the turntable?". The angles used in the hand written answer are used to calculate that time (a time *your* question didn't enquire about). The only angle relevant to your question is $\pi/2$ ($90^\circ$) because the puck leaves the disc at that angle resp. to the line between you and puck.

Comment: @VincentL: the big problem here is that your question is based on another but you didn't represent the original question very well. You then compare answers and superficially conclude they are not the same! And yet the hand written answer doesn't contradict mine at all. It does interpret *relative velocity* in a way that I would not do, hence my edit at the end of the answer.

Comment: @VincentL: I've also added the calculation of time needed to leave the disc after release. It shows that the solution is the same as in the 'mark up' paper but time is 10 times smaller because speed is 10 times higher in your question.

Comment: @Gert I'm sorry I think I've confused you. I'm fine with the first part asking how long it takes to leave the disk. What I am concerned about is the second part, the relative velocity. I'm not sure where 48.6 came from in the answer.

Comment: @VincentL: in their solution, $v_R$ is the projection of $v$ onto the line that is *tangential* to my point $E$. Using trigonometry they calculate $\phi$ first. Then Pythagoras for $v_R$. Honestly, it's just a bit of basic trigonometry.